# How can I remove the gnome-terminal title bar using pixel saver in ubuntu 21.10

Tags: gnome, 21.10

I have a gnome extension pixel saver. When maximizing the terminal, I expect the title bar to be merged with the top bar. However, that does not happen in ubuntu 21.10. How can I change this ?
[image]

Comment: Please do not use a fragment setencelet for the question; please clarify what you are asking. Include a screenshot of what you are trying to get rid of.

Comment: please read [ask] then [edit] accordingly to clarify your question.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of that? That tells you which directory you are in. And if you have many terminal windows open, it will de harder to tell which one is in which directory without that. That also is the title of the window tab and without it, you can't move the window around or anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve what you want provided you change the terminal to use a legacy (classical) titlebar instead of the current CSD (Client Side Decorations) titlebar. The classical title bar only contains the title of the terminal, and no buttons. It will be hidden by the extension "Pixel Saver" when you maximize the terminal.

The option is not exposed in the graphical user interface. So you will need the terminal or dconf-editor to change the setting. With the terminal, this is how you disable the CSD titlebar in order to revert to a classical title bar:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings headerbar false
```

This will cause the traditional menu bar to appear. You can hide that by default in "Preferences - General":  uncheck "Show menubar by default in new terminals". While you are at it, you may prefer setting that through a command as well:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings default-show-menubar false
```

To revert to the default settings in case you change your mind, run the same commands, however change `set` by `reset` and leave out the final argument (`false` in both cases).

Comment: That's good enough for me. Thanks vanadium

Comment: tries this on ubuntu 22, it did not work

Comment: It continues to work for me on Ubuntu 22.04. Quiting and restarting the terminal is needed of course.